# IntellijIDEA: hotkey for jump back and forth a string

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

For example I have a line of code:

```
public static void main() {
}
```

I want a hotkey that points at the start (or end) of the word `public`, then jumps to the next word `static`, and then `void`, etc. The same for me going backward as well.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what shortcuts are assigned to these functions in

`Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Move Caret to Next Word`

`Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Move Caret to Previous Word`

Or you can assign your own.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Right Arrow` and `Ctrl+Left Arrow` would do, wouldn't it?

It's the industry standard for all text-based applications to jump by words rather than characters...